# Helper application cannot be killed and is not launching the main app

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsapplication

I have other questions on SO about making a sandboxed app launch at login, that apparently have no solution: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45260063/logging-from-a-macos-app-into-system-log) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170634/helper-launches-at-login-but-not-app)

As you know, you have to create a helper application that will launch the main app and die.

All tutorials out there say to add this to the helper delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

  // Get the path for the main app bundle from the helper bundle path.
  NSString *basePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
  NSString *path = [basePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
  path = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
  path = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
  path = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];

  [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:path];
  [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:self];
}
```

This code does exactly nothing because the main app is not launched (for the reasons you will see on my other questions) and as a bonus the helper is not killed.

I have tried to kill the helper using a variety of methods, like

```
[NSApp terminate:self];
```

and even this dramatic method

```
NSArray *runningApplications = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
  NSString *theName;
  NSNumber *pid;
  for ( NSDictionary *applInfo in runningApplications ) {
    if ( (theName = [applInfo objectForKey:@"NSApplicationName"]) ) {
      if ( (pid = [applInfo objectForKey:@"NSApplicationProcessIdentifier"]) ) {
        //NSLog( @"Process %@ has pid:%@", theName, pid );  
        if( [theName isEqualToString:@"MyHelper"] ) {
          kill( [pid intValue], SIGKILL );
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Nothing kills the helper.

As another bonus, when I launch the main app manually and it sits on the menu bar, I have the option to choose `QUIT` from the main app itself, so I can quit the app but the main app itself is not killable too, using the same programmatically methods.

What is going on?

I have followed @vadian instructions and it is not working. **I have uploaded a proof of concept project to [here](https://ufile.io/cnqrs)**. You will see that the helper loads but not the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method cannot work because it's incomplete. At least you have to add these two path components to get the path to the executable of the main app (replace `MyApp` with the name of the executable in the MacOS folder)

```
path = [path stringByAddingPathComponent:@"MacOS"];
path = [path stringByAddingPathComponent:@"MyApp"];
```

Nevertheless the recommended and reliable way is to check if the main application is already running and to send an `LaunchConfigurationArgument` to the main application to indicate that the app is launched at login (and of course to use the modern URL related API of `NSBundle` and `NSWorkspace`):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    BOOL alreadyRunning = NO, isActive = NO;
    NSArray *running = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
    for (NSRunningApplication *app in running) {
        if ([[app bundleIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"com.myCompany.MyApp"]) {
            alreadyRunning = YES;
            isActive = [app isActive];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!alreadyRunning || !isActive) {
        NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
        NSMutableArray *pathComponents = [[bundleURL pathComponents] mutableCopy];
        NSUInteger numberOfPathcomponents = [pathComponents count];
        [pathComponents removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(numberOfPathcomponents - 3, 3)];
        [pathComponents addObject:@"MacOS"];
        [pathComponents addObject:@"MyApp"];
        NSURL *newURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];
        NSDictionary *dict = @{NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments: @[@"launchedAtLogin"]};
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplicationAtURL:newURL
                                                      options:NSWorkspaceLaunchWithoutActivation
                                                configuration:dict
                                                        error:nil];
    }
    [NSApp terminate:nil];
}
```

Basically you don't have to quit the helper app from somewhere else. The helper app is supposed to quit itself in any case.

Comment: Are you talking about the binary? shouldn't `[pathComponents addObject:@"Contents"];` be added too before `MacOS`?

Comment: Indeed, you're right. I overlooked the first `stringByDeletingLastPathComponent`. If you delete one of those (remaining 3) you **are** in `Contents`. As you can see in my suggestion only three path components are omitted.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution is not working for me. I have uploaded a proof of concept project to [here](https://ufile.io/cnqrs)

Comment: I'm using this code in 3 different projects (also in Swift). It's supposed to work. There are many other places where the error can come from.

Comment: Please read [this tutorial](https://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/). It describes in detail how to launch a sandboxed app at login.

Comment: I have read all tutorials on the internet and for that reason I have prepared this project that shows it does not work on Sierra for an app that is sandboxed, windowless, menu only. If you ever run the project that I have prepared you will see. Anyway, thanks. I will continue researching. You will see that the main app is marked with Application is Agent on Info.plist because I don't want a dock icon. This is what is preventing the app launching. You remove that and it works.

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWW, I have finally managed to make it work. The problem was probably some kind of corruption in the project. I have created another project and transferred everything from the old one to the new, recreated the helper and now it is working! Did I mention I hate Xcode? Man, this thing is awful. No error whatsoever, no clue, simply not working! THANKS!!!!!!!